# ReportViewer 'varchar' sorting in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, report, report-viewer2010

[Attached is the image showing SCHOOL VISIT Number in first column. I want to sort it in ascending order, How do i sort a VARCHAR in ascending order in report viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa0Ah.png)

Comment: Don't link or attach images. Post your *actual* code and *actual* question. As for *sorting* by any field, that's [explained in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/filter-group-and-sort-data-report-builder-and-ssrs). There's a dialog box with all those settings, even a [step-by-step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/sort-data-in-a-data-region-report-builder-and-ssrs). Have you *tried* it? Did you try editing your report? Do you have an actual question?

Comment: BTW what you highlighted isn't text, it's a date. Which means the question you posted is unrelated to your image. Are you asking how to sort *dates* perhaps? Where did `26-Mar-18` come from? If that's how the data is sorted in the database, you have a design bug in the database. Change the field's type to `date` and sorting will just work. You can change how the date is displayed on the report through the `NumberFormat` property of the textbox, eg by setting it to `dd-MMM-yy`

Comment: I want to sort it based on the SERIAL NUMBER. The first column of the reportviewer.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to guess this? Anyway, the docs explain how to set up sorting. Did you *try* it?

Comment: Yes I did with the help of google. Thanks all for your help.Below is the query.                                                                           
 SELECT * FROM tablename order by CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(column_name,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Column_name),LEN(Column_name)))

Comment: No, that's not what I meant at all. It's also wrong. Or rather, you still haven't explained what you want, you still haven't posted what your data looks like, or what result you want to achieve. You asked about ReportViewer, NOT about querying.

Comment: My data is saved as SV1, SV11,SV12,SV2.. I want to sort it like SV1,SV2,SV11,SV12.